# Ruby On Rails : How to Put Space Inside <%= %> tag in Rails With Multiple Variable Values To Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**I have a form which display the Full name of the customer in read only mode which look like bellow**
[image]

What I require is to have a white space in between First name, Middle name and Last name. I tried many times with different code but it failed, I am giving bellow my code, what to do ?

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Customer Name :</label>  
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <b><input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" value = <%= @lastcustomer.firstname%><%= @lastcustomer.middlename %><%= @lastcustomer.lastname %>  readonly> </b>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by using "#{value} #{value} #{value}" so you can include spaces. So,

Instead of:

```
<input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" value = <%= @lastcustomer.firstname%><%= @lastcustomer.middlename %><%= @lastcustomer.lastname %>  readonly> </b>
```

Do like:

```
<input id='textinput' name='textinput' type='text' placeholder='placeholder' class='form-control input-md' value ='<%= "#{@lastcustomer.firstname} #{@lastcustomer.middlename} #{@lastcustomer.lastname}" %>'  readonly> </b>
```

Comment: That didnt work for me I changed but its not coming into the view. But when I check the inspect Element its there.

Comment: Di you try to `value = '<%= "#{@lastcustomer.firstname} #{@lastcustomer.middlename} #{@lastcustomer.lastname}" %>'`?

Comment: Yes, I did it, what is coming there is only first name, rest are not showing but when I inspect the element using browser its there in the code.

Comment: I updated the code above with `<input id='textinput' name='textinput' type='text' placeholder='placeholder' class='form-control input-md' value ='<%= "#{@lastcustomer.firstname} #{@lastcustomer.middlename} #{@lastcustomer.lastname}" %>'  readonly> </b>` and I tested it and working on me.

Comment: Thank you, now its working fine, as a beginner you helped me so much. I dont know my question was a foolish one or not because I got many down votes for my question :( .

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your customer model that looks like this:

```
def full_name
  [firstname, middlename, lastname].join(' ')
end
```

then, in your view you just use:

```
<%= @lastcustomer.full_name %>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick help :)